# How to compare strings in golang?

Tags: string, go, comparator

I want to make a function that calculates the length of the common segment (starting from the beginning) in two strings. For example:

```
foo:="Makan"
bar:="Makon"
```

The result should be 3.

```
foo:="Indah"
bar:="Ihkasyandehlo"
```

The result should be 1.

Comment: This is not even a question.

Comment: This is like homework for your programming 101 class or something like that. If you don't know how to program something as basic as that you should really be doing your homework instead of asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: that's my question to solve my homework, my homework is ("how to make a simple patricia trie"), i just confused when i want to check  the root key with new key.....

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you are asking because you limited your test cases to ASCII characters.
I've added a Unicode test case and I've included answers for bytes, runes, or both.

<kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/OhcgqCFXPN)</kbd>:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func commonBytes(s, t string) (bytes int) {
    if len(s) > len(t) {
        s, t = t, s
    }
    i := 0
    for ; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] != t[i] {
            break
        }
    }
    return i
}

func commonRunes(s, t string) (runes int) {
    if len(s) > len(t) {
        s, t = t, s
    }
    i := 0
    for ; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] != t[i] {
            break
        }
    }
    return utf8.RuneCountInString(s[:i])
}

func commonBytesRunes(s, t string) (bytes, runes int) {
    if len(s) > len(t) {
        s, t = t, s
    }
    i := 0
    for ; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] != t[i] {
            break
        }
    }
    return i, utf8.RuneCountInString(s[:i])
}

func main() {
    Tests := []struct {
        word1, word2 string
    }{
        {"Makan", "Makon"},
        {"Indah", "Ihkasyandehlo"},
        {"日本語", "日本語"},
    }
    for _, test := range Tests {
        fmt.Println("Words:        ", test.word1, test.word2)
        fmt.Println("Bytes:        ", commonBytes(test.word1, test.word2))
        fmt.Println("Runes:        ", commonRunes(test.word1, test.word2))
        fmt.Print("Bytes & Runes: ")
        fmt.Println(commonBytesRunes(test.word1, test.word2))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Words:         Makan Makon
Bytes:         3
Runes:         3
Bytes & Runes: 3 3
Words:         Indah Ihkasyandehlo
Bytes:         1
Runes:         1
Bytes & Runes: 1 1
Words:         日本語 日本語
Bytes:         9
Runes:         3
Bytes & Runes: 9 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you were working with Unicode characters, the result could be quite different.
Try for instance using [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRuneInString).

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/rULJtvS46V):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unicode/utf8"

func index(s1, s2 string) int {
    res := 0
    for i, w := 0, 0; i < len(s2); i += w {
        if i >= len(s1) {
            return res
        }
        runeValue1, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s1[i:])
        runeValue2, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s2[i:])
        if runeValue1 != runeValue2 {
            return res
        }
        if runeValue1 == utf8.RuneError || runeValue2 == utf8.RuneError {
            return res
        }
        w = width
        res = i + w
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    foo := "日本本a語"
    bar := "日本本b語"
    fmt.Println(index(foo, bar))
    foo = "日本語"
    bar = "日otest"
    fmt.Println(index(foo, bar))
    foo = "\xF0"
    bar = "\xFF"
    fmt.Println(index(foo, bar))
}
```

Here, the result would be:

- 9 (3 common runes of width '3')
- 3 (1 rune of width '3')
- 0 (invalid rune, meaning [`utf8.RuneError`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#pkg-constants))

Comment: Don't ignore errors. For example, `foo = "\xF0"; bar = "\xFF"; fmt.Println(index(foo, bar))` prints `1` not `0`: http://play.golang.org/p/osAFlIubxZ.

Comment: @peterSO Indeed. I missed the `utf8.RuneError` case.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this. Please note, this will not handle UTF 8, only ascii.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func equal(s1, s2 string) int {
    eq := 0
    if len(s1) > len(s2) {
        s1, s2 = s2, s1
    }
    for key, _ := range s1 {
        if s1[key] == s2[key] {
            eq++
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return eq
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(equal("buzzfizz", "buzz"))
    fmt.Println(equal("Makan", "Makon"))
    fmt.Println(equal("Indah", "Ihkasyandehlo"))
}
```