# Easy way to get a sub-string/sub-slice of up to N characters/elements in Go

Tags: string, go, slice

In Python I can slice a string to get a sub-string of up to N characters and if the string is too short it will simply return the rest of the string, e.g.

```
"mystring"[:100] # Returns "mystring"
```

What's the easiest way to do the same in Go? Trying the same thing panics:

```
"mystring"[:100] // panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

Of course, I can write it all manually:

```
func Substring(s string, startIndex int, count int) string {
    maxCount := len(s) - startIndex
    if count > maxCount {
        count = maxCount
    }
    return s[startIndex:count]
}

fmt.Println(Substring("mystring", 0, n))
```

But that's rather a lot of work for something so simple and (I would have thought) common. What's more, I don't know how to generalise this function to slices of other types, since Go doesn't support generics. I'm hoping there is a better way. Even `Math.Min()` doesn't easily work here, because it expects and returns `float64`.

Comment: What is too complex about checking the string length? If you need to do it more than once, you can put it in a function.

Comment: Sure, I can put it in a function. I can also write such a function for every type for which I need to get a sub-slice of up to N elements. It's a way that works. I'm asking if there is a better way.

Comment: How many types do you have that you need to do this? Yes it's a little extra code, but you write it once for the type you have and you're done. You're free to write a generic version using reflection, but you will probably never see that in practice.

Comment: `Math.Min` expects and returns floats, but that doesn't stop you casting between ints and floats, so I wouldn't say it "doesn't work here". Stdlib is under the same restrictions as your own code, so if there isn't a built-in to do this (there isn't) then a stdlib function would have the same options you do: write a function per type of slice, or use reflection. I have to wonder though, how often do you have to do this with slices, and why does it come up so much? I don't think I've ever needed this functionality, in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while a function remains the recommended solution (even if it has to be implemented for slices with different type), it wouldn't work well with `string`.

`fmt.Println(Substring("世界mystring", 0, 5)`) would actually print `世��` instead of `世界mys`.
See "[Code points, characters, and runes](https://blog.golang.org/strings#TOC_5.)": a character may be represented by a number of different sequences of code points, and therefore different sequences of UTF-8 bytes.
And in Go, a "code point" is a `rune` (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076457/6309)).

Using `rune` would be more robust (again, in case of strings)

```
func SubstringRunes(s string, startIndex int, count int) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    length := len(runes)
    maxCount := length - startIndex
    if count > maxCount {
        count = maxCount
    }
    return string(runes[startIndex:count])
}
```

See it in action [in this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-rRtlq_vWin).